# Unsure why this question was off-topic

Tags: discussion

[This question](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/q/40264/30797) was put on hold as off-topic because it was a nutrition only question (the same reason that all questions that are to the effect of "should I do X diet plan?") However, since it's specifically about storing protein powder in the freezer and not asking about nutritional benefits per se, I think that this question was improperly closed. Almost every weightlifter uses protein powder. This question seems like it'd be a good addition to the knowledge base, even if the answer is simple.

Since I'm new to the SE, I assume I'm missing something. Where is the flaw in my thought process?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alec is correct. While nutrition was originally included as being acceptable on the site, quite a few years back it was decided that only questions about nutrition in the context of an actual workout regimen were on topic.

I admit, it's hard to define sometimes, but as Alec highlights, your question is solely about how to store protein mixes. I tried to figure out a way to bring it on topic, but unfortunately I couldn't come up with a good way.

Comment: Just for clarification, and my soft ego :), this isn't my question. Just a curious bystander.

Comment: @LuxClaridge - Ah, ok. Hope I helped then. :) Sorry, I didn't go back to check the link of who posted it originally.

Comment: IDK if discussion questions still get a check (I don't meta very often). But I'm accepting yours as you make the valid point that the question was about protein storage, which does seem off-topic. Thanks!

Comment: I would have shut it down too.

Answer (score 3):

I'm on the fence. I probably wouldn't have closed it, but being on the fence, I won't overturn John's vote either, until we've discussed it.

It's a good question, don't get me wrong. But the reason it might fall outside the scope is that it deals only with food, and not with food as it relates to exercise. As such, it may be more suited for the cooking site. Or perhaps even biology.

https://fitness.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

That said, you do mention that this is specifically for post-workout meals.

> I'm wondering if I include protein powder in the ziplock bags, if that will affect the protein benefits for my after workout routine.

I'm just thinking "out loud" here, but as it relates to exercise, the answer to your question is just "no", which would be a bit lackluster. The real details lie in the chemistry, which is why it seems a bit misplaced.

@JohnP - Thoughts?

Comment: Just for clarification, and my soft ego :), this isn't my question. Just a curious bystander.